# Excluding directories which no read access in Unix find command

Tags: unix

I am running a `find` command to search for files recursively. Whenever it comes across a directory for which the user does not have read access, the `find` throws an access error which is causing problem when the script is run.

Is there a way by which I can limit the `find` to only the directories on which the user which is running the script has read access?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit `find` to only directories that the user running `find` has read access in by using the `-readable` flag, but that's not going to suppress the error messages because it's got to call `access()` on it in order to determine whether a directory/file is readable or not. You'd have to pipe those out or something:

```
find / -readable 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Hi..thanks for the reply...I am on Solaris and it seems there's nothing called `readable` flag.